# this.state react

Tags: reactjs

I'm student and doing this kind of project the first time, also first time in React and this syntax. I have followed some tutorials but are stuck now.

When you click all numbers shall be added together.

Where am I doing this wrong? Is it where I parse the input? I have tried different ways all weekend but don't manage. Please help me get further.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './App.css';
import Button from './components/Buttons'; 
import Input from './components/Inputs';
import ClearButton from './components/ClearButtons';


class App extends Component {



  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      input: "",
      operator: ""
    };
  }


  addToInput = val => {
    this.setState({ input: this.state.input + val });
  }

  // If this.state.input is not empty then add zero
  // If this.state.input is not blank (another number has already been added in)
  addZeroToInput = val => {
    if (this.state.input !== "") {
      this.setState({ input: this.state.input + val });
    }
  };

  // Input = blank 
  clearInput = () => {
    this.setState({ input: "" });
  };

  add = () => {
    this.setState({ input: ""});
    this.state.operator = "plus";

    if (this.state.operator == "plus") {
      this.setState({
        input:
          parseInt(this.state.input) +
          parseInt(this.state.input)
      });
    }
  };

  mult = () => {
    this.setState({ input: "" });
    this.state.operator = "multiply";

    if (this.state.operator == "multiply") {
      this.setState({
        input:
          parseInt(this.state.input) *
          parseInt(this.state.input)
      });
    }
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="row">
            <Input>{this.state.input}</Input>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <Button handleClick={this.addToInput}>7</Button>
            <Button handleClick={this.addToInput}>8</Button>
            <Button handleClick={this.addToInput}>9</Button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <Button handleClick={this.addToInput}>4</Button>
            <Button handleClick={this.addToInput}>5</Button>
            <Button handleClick={this.addToInput}>6</Button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <Button handleClick={this.addToInput}>1</Button>
            <Button handleClick={this.addToInput}>2</Button>
            <Button handleClick={this.addToInput}>3</Button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <Button handleClick={this.add}>+</Button>
            <Button handleClick={this.addZeroToInput}>0</Button>
            <Button handleClick={this.multiply}>*</Button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <ClearButton handleClear={this.clearInput}>Clear</ClearButton>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I see several issues with your code. One BIG no-no is direct state assignment like `this.state.operator = "plus"`. You just cannot do that. Then you seem to be manipulating (adding, especially) strings & integers without distinction, which leads to confusion. `3 + 4` won't be the same as `"3" + "4"`. Finally, could you add the code from your Button component, as it appears to be responsible for passing the value back to the `addToInput` method.

Comment: I added the code from the button component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from what I can see in your code, you are successfully adding numbers (digits) to your input, but you're having an issue when attempting to parse your input digits to apply the chosen operator.

What you want to do when an operator is pressed is:
1. parse your input into single digits
2. apply the chosen operator to the parsed digits
3. output the result (replacing the input?)

1. can be done with `string.split`
2. can be done with `array.reduce`
3. is a simple `setState`

```js
add = () => {
  const { input } = this.state
  const digits = input.split('')
  const output = digits.reduce((sum, digit) => sum + parseInt(digit, 10), 0)
  this.setState({ input: output })
  // or if you want to preserve the input, add an output key to the state and
  // this.setState({ output })
}

multiply = () => {
  const { input } = this.state
  const digits = input.split('')
  const output = digits.reduce((product, digit) => product * parseInt(digit, 10), 1)
  this.setState({ input: output })
  // or if you want to preserve the input, add an output key to the state and
  // this.setState({ output })
}
```

Note that this limits you to single digit operations. It'd be a lot easier to add a space key to delimit numbers, and then transform your input into numbers with `input.split(' ')` which would store all numbers (even multiple digits) neatly into an array.

Answer (score 0):

> Now when I click 4444 + it show 8888 but it shall show 16.

Your add function includes this:

```
this.setState({
  input:
    parseInt(this.state.input) +
    parseInt(this.state.input)
});
```

in this case `this.state.input` would be `"4444"`, you parse it to an integer and basically add it to itself, which is why it's `8888`.

If your desired output is to add every digit to each other, as in `4+4+4+4`, then you'll need to split `this.state.input` by each digit, parse it to an integer and then add it together.

```
> "4444".split("")
[ '4', '4', '4', '4' ]
> "4444".split("").map(Number)
[ 4, 4, 4, 4 ]
> "4444".split("").map(Number).reduce((x, y) => x + y)
16
```

---

Unrelated, but you should follow @Hemadri's advice on how to set up the Button's `handleClick`. Or, alternatively, just do this:

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.addToInput(e)}>1</button>
```

```
addToInput = event => {
  this.setState({input: this.state.input + event.target.innerText});
}
```

---

Additionally don't mutate state directly, use the `setState()` function.

You can also just combine this:

```
this.setState({input: ""});
this.state.operator = "plus";
```

into this:

```
this.setState({
  input: "",
  operator: "plus"
});
```

And get rid of `if (this.state.operator == "plus")` since you just set the operator to `plus` so you don't need to check for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these code inside
1.add function

```
    var values = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.input.length; i++) {
        values += parseInt(this.state.input[i])
    }

    this.setState({
        input: values
    });
```

2.multiply function

```
    var values = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.input.length; i++) {
        values *= parseInt(this.state.input[i])
    }

    this.setState({
        input: values
    });
```

You are taking the input values as a string block.To solve, you have to take each value from that string and parse like this.